# How to make sure that JSON extractor always gets the proper value from response?

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using JSON extractor to parse the response but sometimes the response return a blank value in the given index and that time I want to make sure that we move to another index to get the proper value.

For e.g. my JSON path expression is

```
$.CM[0].id
```

When application returns a blank value in the 0 index, that time I get the default value which is mentioned in the JSON extractor, instead what I want is whenever my script returns a blank value for 0 index, script should search for the value in next index i.e. 1. So when $.CM[0].id fails to get the value, application should search for $.CM[1].id and get the response.

What should be my approach? Should I use some sort of bean shell scripting or should try to use if controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language.

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns JSON response
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).CM.ID

   ids.eachWithIndex { id, i ->
       log.info('Trying id: ' + i)
       if (id.size() > 0) {
           log.info('Found non-empty ID: ' + id)
           vars.put('ID', id)
           return true
       }
   }
   ```
3. The above code will put a non-empty ID value (if any) into `ID` JMeter Variable, you will be able to refer extracted value as `${ID}` or `${__V(ID)}` where required.

References:

- [Groovy Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy Each Loop Examples](http://grails.asia/groovy-each-examples)
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)